# Probability calculation Poisson Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I need to calculate
$$P(N(4)\ge6|S(4)=3)$$
where $N(t)$ is the number of events that have ocurred between $0$ and $t$. And $S(n)$ is the arrival time of the $n$th event. My calculation so far is
$$P(N(4)\ge6|S(4)=3)=\frac{P(N(4)\ge6,S(4)=3)}{P(S(4)=3)}=\frac{P(N(4)-N(3)\ge2)}{P(S(4)=3)}=\frac{P(N(1)\ge2)}{P(S(4)=3)}$$
Since the fourth event ocurred at time $3$ and up to time $4$ there were at least $6$ events, thus between time $3$ and $4$ there must be at least 2 events. The Problem here is that I dont know where im worng since I cannot calculate the denominar since $S(4)$ is gamma distributed.

Comment: Hint: Poisson processes have some special property that implies that the answer is $P(N(1)\ge2)$ itself. By the way, your second equality is incorrect: $N(4)-N(3)\ge2$ is a consequence of $N(4)\ge6,\, S(4)=3$, but it is not equivalent.

Comment: Indeed, in fact $\{N(4){\geq}6, S(4){=}3\}=\{N(4){-}N(3){\geq}2\}\cap\{ S(4){=}3\}$ . Of note, that is an intersection of *independent* events.

Answer (score 1):

You are evaluating the conditional probability that *at least* 6 events occur *within* time interval $(0..4]$, given that the fourth event occurred *at* time $3$.

That is equal to the probability that *at least* 2 events occur *within* time interval $(3..4]$.  Which is equal to the probability that *at least* two events occur *with* time interval $(0..1]$.

---

The event $\{N(4){\geqslant}6, S(4){=}3\}$ is equal to $\{N(4){-}N(3){\geqslant}2\}\cap\{S(4){=}3\}$ and since $(3..4]$ and $[3..3]$  are disjoint intervals, this is the intersection of *independent events* (By the nature of a Poisson process).  So:.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(N(4){\geqslant}6\mid S(4){=}3) &=\mathsf P(N(4){-}N(3){\geqslant}2\mid S(4){=}3)\\[1ex] &= \mathsf P(N(4){-}N(3){\geqslant}2)\end{align}$$

And by the constant rate property: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(N(4){\geqslant}6\mid S(4){=}3) &= \mathsf P(N(1)\geqslant 1)\hspace{14ex}\end{align}$$